# Dynamo DB Table Updation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

My requirement is to update partition keys in a table in DynamoDB. In order to update Partition key, the older record should be deleted and new record with updated partition key should be added.
The issue is my table size is around 400 MB and it has around 2 million records.

If I scan whole table then its not efficient and high memory consumption happens.
Wanted to do batch scan of tables.
My ambiguity is, since new elements keep on getting added (because of partition key updation as mentioned above), batch calls mind not end itself.

I was able to do batch scan using LastEvaluatedKey that dynamodb provided in updating other attributed.
Wanted to know if LastEvaluatedKey will work when updating partition key (when new record gets added and older record gets deleted).

Comment: Please use universal measurements. A lot of people aren't going to know what are *lakh records*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're doing your batch job, but last evaluated key is a pointer to the last item you read in the scan. Even if that item is deleted, the pointer remains in that position and continues reading forward on subsequent requests.

You mention you continue to write into DynamoDB, of those writes don't have the correct Partition key format you're aiming to achieve, then you will have to continually start your Scan to keep getting those items which need changing.

So if you're looking to update all the items, even when new ones are coming in you should probably configure a new table, anything that you scan gets written to the new table. Any new items written to the source table will be consumed by DynamoDB stream and you place a Lambda function to put it in the new table. That means that you only scan the table once.

Keep in mind 400MB is an extremely small table. If you stopped writes for 1 minute you could make the conversion with no interruptions.

Comment: Hello Lee. I am writing a python script. Here my goal is to update partition key(partition key is bascially a timestamp). Change the timestamp to current timestamp. I have 20Lakh records. 400MB is the size of table. Adding new records what i meant was dynamo db when updating partition key, deletes the oer record and creates a newer record. Currently I am doing scan for whole table..which means loading all 20Lakh records at time. 1. Is loading 20lakh records at a time(total size 400MB) is fine?. 2. If not fine then any way to load in batches

Comment: 1. It's fine, but DynamoDB will always return batches (pages) of 1MB 2. You can use parallel scan if you want to break the table up into chunks

Comment: table_name = 'tableName'
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

scan_result = table.scan()

for item in scan_result['Items'] This is what I am doing to scan the table.  I guess it loads all 400MB at once right?

Comment: No it does not, it loads 1MB.

Comment: Thanks Lee for all the clarifications. Then I hope I can continue with this code which I posted in above comment.

Comment: Then I need to paginate the results right to scan all data using LastEvaluatedKey. Again like this LastEvaluatedKey works when we are updating partition keys?(the record newly gets created and older one gets recorded in dynamodb)

Comment: You can hold 400MB in memory easily, paginate until you have all items, then update them.